# If This is Clicked Show This Else Hide This

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have seen other if else examples on here but nothing specifically addressing jquery "if clicked show this else hide this". Here's a simple code example. I would like to know the cleanest way to show the .redStuff when #red is clicked else hide it and show the other classes when the relative id is clicked.
Here is the HTML:

```css
.redStuff, .blueStuff, .greenStuff {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="color">
  <li id="red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li id="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li id="green"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="redStuff">Red Stuff</div>
<div class="blueStuff">Blue Stuff</div>
<div class="greenStuff">Green Stuff</div>
```

Comment: You want to show ONLY the element that is clicked, right? So if Red Stuff is showing and you click Blue Stuff, you want it to show Blue Stuff only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data attributes is easy once you get the idea.

css

```
.redStuff, .blueStuff, .greenStuff {
  display: none;
 }
```

html

```
<ul id="color">
  <li id="red" data-color="red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li id="blue" data-color="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li id="green" data-color="green"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="redStuff" data-content="red">Red Stuff</div>
<div class="blueStuff" data-content="blue">Blue Stuff</div>
<div class="greenStuff" data-content="green">Green Stuff</div>
```

jquery

```
       // no need for the ids or classes
       // we set data attributes for the html
  $("li[data-color]").click(function(){
       // next line is for second click, to hide the prev div element
    $("div[data-content]").hide();
       // we are getting the data-color attr value here 
       // and for readibility  we assigned it to a variable called color
    var color = $(this).data("color");
       // find the div with the same content and show 
    $("div[data-content='"+color+"']").show();
  });
```

[jsfiddle link to play with codes](https://jsfiddle.net/frknrhn/7ebxy67c/)

Answer (score 0):

Numerous ways to approach this depending on complexity of the layout.

If the order is the same relationship between the `<li>`'s and the `<div>` you can use `index()`. Adding a common class would be helpful

```
<div class="redStuff  stuff">Red Stuff</div>
```

JS

```
$('#color li').click(function(){
    // "this" is the element event occurred on
    var index = $(this).index();
    // hide all the "stuff" class and show the matching indexed one
    $('.stuff').hide().eq(index).show();

});
```

Or add `data-` attributes to target specific element so that index order becomes irrelevant

HTML

```
<li id="red"><a href="#" data-target=".redStuff">Red</a></li>
```

JS

```
$('#color a').click(function(){
   $('.stuff').hide().filter( $(this).data('target') ).show();
});
```

Or by using ID to create a selector

```
$('#color li').click(function(){
     $('.stuff').hide().filter('.' + this.id +'Stuff').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

It's not an "If Then Else" statement exactly, but it accomplishes the logical objective.

```
var $stuff = $(".redStuff, .blueStuff, .greenStuff");
var $colors = $("#color li a");
$colors.on("click", function(){
    // get color from parent (li) id
    var color = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    // turn all stuff off (because we don't know what came last)
    $stuff.attr({style: null});
    // turn on clicked stuff class
    $("." + color + "Stuff").attr({style: "display:block;"});
});
```

Demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhd6Lnxr/).